# Webservice method returning empty when called from .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm doing some tests with a client's webservice. The WSDL is defined like this:

```
<xs:element name="CorretoresGeralRequest"> 
    <xs:complexType> 
        <xs:sequence> 
            <xs:element name="codEvPesq" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/> 
            <xs:element name="nmeEvPesq" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/> 
        </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="CorretoresGeralResponse"> 
    <xs:complexType> 
        <xs:sequence> 
            <xs:element name="resultCorretoresGeral" type="tr:ResultCorretoresGeral" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/> 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element> 
<xs:complexType name="ResultCorretoresGeral"> 
    <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="corretoresGeral" type="tr:CorretorGeral" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/> 
        <xs:element name="listCompleta" type="xs:boolean"/> 
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
<xs:complexType name="CorretorGeral"> 
    <xs:sequence> 
        <xs:element name="codAtiv" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/> 
        <xs:element name="dscAtiv" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/> 
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

When I use soapUI to call the method passing a parameter, it returns me correctly:
[image]

However, when I create a web reference for it in my project and call it via C# code, it returns me an empty array(ServicoTeste is the name of the webreferece I've created for the service):
[image]

```
ServicoTeste.TransporteClient servico = new ServicoTeste.TransporteClient();
ServicoTeste.CorretoresGeralRequest request = new ServicoTeste.CorretoresGeralRequest();
ServicoTeste.ResultCorretoresGeral[] response;

request.nmeEvPesq = "MAS";
response = servico.CorretoresGeral(request);
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Paste your code as a text, not as an image..

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of SOAP. It should not matter, but their service probably isn't written in .NET and expects a slightly different message format. Compare the messages from both clients.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do that? Could you provide me any links that would be useful to me?

Comment: @devGabriel search the web for Fiddler (an HTTP traffic inspection tool) and WCF Tracing (which writes incoming and outgoing messages to a trace file).